# How to get the plan the robot will exactly follow

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS Navigation stack on a robot & I want to access the exact plan the robot will follow. I know the [~/plan](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn#Published_Topics) topic publishes the plan but the description of the same topic (in the same link) says that it is used primarily for visualization purposes. I interpreted it as "the plan published on ~/plan will be the approximate plan the robot will follow & not the exact plan".

How can I access the exact plan the robot will follow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403820/how-to-get-the-plan-the-robot-will-exactly-follow/) by [user1928](https://answers.ros.org/users/98610/user1928/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The exact plan the robot will follow will depend on what the local planner decides. For instance, if the local planner can avoid dynamic objects, it might make an entirely different path to follow. If the local planner only follows the global path, it will depend on if the path is valid for the kinematics of the robot. I would argue that these are approximate by nature, I'm afraid.

---

Originally posted by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) with karma: 501 on 2022-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1